# Counting Distinct rows based on column using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables, A parent (table a) and a child (Table B). For each parent there can be multiple children (rows). What I need is if certain criteria is met in the children, I need it to count as 1.

Currently, my code is counting each child to the parent and it's not supposed to work that way. Here's my code simplified.

```
SELECT 
  cl.clientID, cl.code, cl.cName, 
  COUNT(case when e.errorCode NOT IN('DP','RB','WP','PE','OV') then c.rID end) as rateCount,
  SUM(case when e.errorCode NOT IN('DP','RB','WP','PE','OV') then e.refundDue else 0.0 end) as rateAmount,
  COUNT(case when e.errorCode IN('DP','RB','WP','PE','OV') then c.rID end) as paymentCount, 
  SUM(case when e.errorCode IN('DP','RB','WP','PE','OV') then e.refundDue else 0.0 end) as paymentAmount 

  FROM claims c 

  INNER JOIN clients cl ON cl.code=c.client 
  INNER JOIN entries e ON e.rID=c.rID 

  WHERE 

  status='closed' AND c.carrierID IN(3909) AND 
  (c.dateon >= '20170624' AND c.dateon < '20171220') 

  GROUP BY cl.clientID, cl.code, cl.cName ORDER BY cl.cName ASC
```

So, again, in the count statement, instead of counting 1 instance when the criteria is met, it's counting all the children. What connects the parent (claims) to child (entries) is the parents rID. I hope this is clear, but just to be sure,

**Claims**

```
rID   name
------------------
1     Damien
2     Jim
```

**Entries**

```
eID  rID  name
------------------
1    1    Yeye
2    1    Juju
3    1    Nao
4    1    Ty
5    2    Pai
6    2    Cha
7    2    Jac
```

So in this case, for Damien i should get a 1, as in yes, he has children and Jim should also get a 1.

Here's the results from the above SQL:

[image: results]

Here are the tables:

[image: Carriers Table]

[image: clients table]

[image: claims table]

[image: entries table]

Comment: you need to provide a more thorough example where count would not be equal to 0 or 1

Comment: Could you post a sample of `Clients` and how does it relate to `Claims`? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the schema for the three tables `claims`, `clients`, and `entries`, relevant sample data for each table, and expected output.

Comment: i've updated my original post with more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're not really "counting", rather,  you're setting a flag. This should get you what you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
  c.name 
  ,HasChild = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM entries e WHERE e.rID = c.rID and e.errorCode NOT IN('DP','RB','WP','PE','OV')) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END    
FROM claims c
```

EDIT:
Without sample data from each table, I can't really test this, but it appears that you may need to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`. Try this:

```
SELECT
    cl.clientID
    ,cl.code
    ,cl.cName
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN e.errorCode NOT IN ('DP', 'RB', 'WP', 'PE', 'OV') THEN
                    c.rID END
          )                                                                        AS rateCount
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN e.errorCode NOT IN ('DP', 'RB', 'WP', 'PE', 'OV') THEN
                  e.refundDue ELSE 0.0 END
        )                                                                          AS rateAmount
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN e.errorCode IN ('DP', 'RB', 'WP', 'PE', 'OV') THEN c.rID END) AS paymentCount
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN e.errorCode IN ('DP', 'RB', 'WP', 'PE', 'OV') THEN
                  e.refundDue ELSE 0.0 END
        )                                                                          AS paymentAmount
FROM claims        c
INNER JOIN clients cl ON cl.code = c.client
INNER JOIN entries e ON e.rID = c.rID
WHERE status = 'closed'
    AND c.carrierID IN (3909)
    AND (c.dateon >= '20170624' AND c.dateon < '20171220')
GROUP BY cl.clientID
    ,cl.code
    ,cl.cName
ORDER BY cl.cName ASC;
```

Comment: Let me give that a shot... I thought about it and in reality, what i need to count is the number of parents if i child exists

Comment: Can you provide some more sample data where the counts wouldn't be equal to 1?

Comment: I've updated the original code to show everything that's going on. If that entries table wasn't there than it would be a simple select * from claims where carrierID=3909. That would give me the actual claim count i need, but since i need to break it down further, that's where everything comes crashing down :(

Comment: so i tried the has and it says it wants the c.rID in the group by... when i do that, it gives me a row for every entry. Instead of giving me 1 line per clietn. which doesn't work for me. It should show each Client once and then tally up the amount of claims based on the error codes. now it's showing me the same client 10, 20, 30 times depending on how many entries there are for the claims that belong to the client.

Comment: Maybe that comment isn't for my answer? My query doesn't use any aggregates or `GROUP BY` clause...

Comment: can you check out my initial post. I've updated the sql to show all the code i'm using. The way it works is it should be showing me, based on the claims, all the clients listed out once and then show me how many claims the client has based on the error codes that are found in the entries. Hope that makes sense

Comment: You really need to provide more sample data.

Comment: Refresh... added what the data should look like. What the red boxes are showing is that those numbers are off. It's counting the entries and not the actual claims. The total should be 8, not 15. Also added what the tables look like. Hope this clears things up

Comment: Looks like the COUNT(DISTINCT...) did it! Can't believe that was all that was missing. Thanks for all the help and sorry for the delay but you rock!!!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of subqueries you could try something like:

```
SELECT cl.clientID, cl.code, cl.cName,
case (select count(*) from entries e where e.rID=c.rID and e.errorCode
NOT IN('DP','RB','WP','PE','OV')) when 0 then 0 else 1 end  as rateCount 
FROM claims c 
    INNER JOIN clients cl ON cl.code=c.client 

GROUP BY cl.clientID, cl.code, cl.cName, rateCount  ORDER BY cl.cName ASC
```

**ANOTHER APPROACH**

Using common table expressions you can try something like:

```
WITH CTE AS (
select c.client, CASE count(*) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS rateCount  
from entries e inner join claims c on c.rID = e.rID where e.errorCode
    NOT IN('DP','RB','WP','PE','OV') GROUP BY c.client
)   
SELECT cl.clientID, cl.code, cl.cName, coalesce( rateCount,0) as rateCount  
from CTE c right join clients cl on cl.code = c.client
```

Comment: that will produce the same exact results. It will count the number of entries. In reality, what i need to count is the number of parents if i child exists

Comment: Sorry, I added the `case` clause to return 1 in case `count > 0`

Comment: The problem with that, and i tried that before, instead of grouping all the clients together, it lists a client for each claim it finds... damien 1, damien 1, damien 1 (3 kids so it lists it each time)

Comment: Really? Even with the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: Please try the alternate way I've just posted.

Comment: i'm going to edit my post to show the rest of the code. I tried to keep it at a minimum but maybe it will help if you see it all. Refresh to see the changes :)

Comment: It would be more useful to have more sample data where the count should not be 0 or 1.